# How to add a process bar when you waiting for a response from the server

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django

could someone help me with one problem? I want to add a process bar when you waiting for a response from the server (Django 3.x).

Step to reproduce:

1. On the page 'A' we have the form.
2. Enter data to form.
3. Submit POST request by clicking to button on the page 'A'.
4. Waiting for getting the result on the page 'A'.
5. Get the result on the page 'A'.

So, I want to add process bar after 4th and before 5th points on the page 'A'. When you will get the result on the page 'A' it should disappear.

Python 3.7
Django 3.x

Comment: Your question is too broad, and opinion based. This question needs more focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `nprogress`, it's a library used for progress bars. Use this inside the interceptor where you can config it for displaying only when request is in progress until finished.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this. I think using jquery would be easier. Basically you just need to prevent submitting the page and do an Ajax request to server. something like

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form").submit(function (e) {
            // prevent page loading
            e.preventDefault(e);
            $('#loadinAnimation').show();

            // preapre formdata

            $.ajax({
                type: "yourRequestType",
                url: "yourUrlEndpoint",
                data: formdata,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#loadinAnimation').hide();
                    // do rest of the work with data
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

and show appropriate loading animation in your html part

```
<div id='loadinAnimation' style='display:none'>
    <div>loading gif</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using UiKit Library in Javascript on your Django Template Page.
Below code is when a file is Uploaded

In your template file (template.html)

```
<body>
..
  <form>
    <progress id="js-progressbar" class="uk-progress" value="0" max="100" hidden></progress> 
    ...
    <div class="uk-alert-danger uk-margin-top uk-hidden" id="upload_error" uk-alert></div>
   ...
  </form>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var bar = document.getElementById('js-progressbar');

    UIkit.upload('.js-upload-list', {

        url: '',
        name : "customer-docs",
        params :{
            "csrfmiddlewaretoken":"{{csrf_token}}"
        },
        method : "POST",
        concurrent:1,
        allow:'*.(csv|xlsx)',

        beforeSend: function (environment) {
            console.log('beforeSend', arguments);
            // The environment object can still be modified here. 
            // var {data, method, headers, xhr, responseType} = environment;

        },
        beforeAll: function (args,files) {
            console.log('beforeAll', arguments);
        },
        load: function () {
            console.log('load', arguments);
        },
        error: function (files) {
            console.log("---------------")
        },
        complete: function () {
            console.log('complete', arguments);
        },

        loadStart: function (e) {
            console.log('loadStart', arguments);

            bar.removeAttribute('hidden');
            bar.max = e.total;
            bar.value = e.loaded;
        },

        progress: function (e) {
            console.log('progress', arguments);

            bar.max = e.total;
            bar.value = e.loaded;
        },

        loadEnd: function (e) {
            console.log('loadEnd', arguments);

            bar.max = e.total;
            bar.value = e.loaded;
        },

        completeAll: function (data) {
            console.log('completeAll', arguments);
            console.log('completeAll', data);
            let redirect_loc = ""

            setTimeout(function () {
                bar.setAttribute('hidden', 'hidden');
            }, 1000);

            // This is the response from your POST method of views.py
            data.responseText = JSON.parse(data.responseText)

            if(data.responseText.status == 201){
                // swal is another library to show sweet alert pop ups
                swal({
                    icon: data.responseText.status_icon,
                    closeOnClickOutside: true,
                    text: data.responseText.message,
                    buttons: {
                        Done: true
                    },
                }).then((value) => {
                  switch (value) {
                    case "Done":
                      window.location.href = ""
                      break;
                  }
                });
            }
            else if(data.responseText.status == 500){
                swal({
                    icon: data.responseText.status_icon,
                    closeOnClickOutside: true,
                    text:  data.responseText.message,
                    buttons: {
                        Ok: true
                    },
                }).then((value) => {
                  switch (value) {
                    case "Ok":
                      window.location.href = ""
                      break;
                  }
                });
            }
        }
    });

   // This block of code is to restrict user to upload only specific FILE formats (below example is for CSV & XLSX files)
   (function() {
        var _old_alert = window.alert;
        window.alert = function(e) {
            
            console.log(e)
            if(e.includes("csv|xlsx") || e.includes("Invalid file type"))  {
                $("#upload_error").html("Invalid file format. Valid formats are CSV, XLSX").removeClass('uk-hidden')
            }else if(e.includes("Internal Server Error"))  {
                $("#upload_error").html("Internal Server Error Kindly upload Documents again").removeClass('uk-hidden')
            } 
            else {
                _old_alert.apply(window,arguments);
                $("#upload_error").addClass('uk-hidden').html("")
            }
        };
    })();

});
</script>
```

On your views.py you can do your computation and once done, you can return a response like below

```
resp_json = {
                "status" : 201,
                "status_icon" : "success",
                "url" : "/",
                "message": message
            }
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(resp_json))
```

For more info on SWAL (Sweet Alerts), visit https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/